# Automatic Measurements in Xaml using"*"

Tags: xaml

I was trying to adjust the width of a button using *, because I wanted it to resize when the application goes into fulscreen or something like that. I was able to change the Grid with this, but when I tried it with the actual button, I got this error: XLS0431.

```
<Grid Width="800" Height="450">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions Width="100*" />
    <Button Width="5*" Height="20*" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The star-notation is used only by the `Grid`, for its row- and column-definitions. In your case, I think there's no need to specify `Width` and `Height` for the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button (or any other FrameworkElement) to grow in width with its container set its `HorizontalAlignment` to '`Stretch`'. Depending on the Button's Content also set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to 'Stretch'
The '*' syntax only applies to properties of type [GridLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlength.-ctor?view=net-5.0#system-windows-gridlength-ctor(system-double-system-windows-gridunittype)), i.e. Height and Width of RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition of Grids.